# How to share web.config file between MVC 3 and MVC 4 Project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I have a MVC 3.0 and MVC 4.0 Projects side by side

[image]

I did this for the resource sharing between two solutions. it is works fine when i change the config file. changes in details.

In MVC 3.

```
<assemblies>
  <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</assemblies>

<pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

When i remove the `<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />` MVC 4 is working fine. after i debug the project in MVC 3.0 it showing an error msg(`The type or namespace name 'Ajax' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`
) because of i remove the "System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0" , if i have to run that means i have to place the refreance again. here i am doing everyting manually, is there is any way to automatic do this ?

For example, two xml files in server side i read that xml file and replace the config file.

**Already Tried.**

In MVC 4 project i used the `WebConfigurationManager` to remove the refreance it works , after i opened the MVC 3 it shows that error msg.

Comment: Interesting problem, I am curious to know why you need to do this?

Comment: Actually, i have an MVC helper, i have to test that in both 4.0 and 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new build configuration for Mvc3 and run a pre-build event that will overwrite your web.config, it's an idea I've adopted from [Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx).

If you follow the link the only difference for your set up would be that you would have a config called

```
Web.Config.Mvc3  (and possibly Web.Config.Mvc3Release)
```

and leave Mvc as your default builds

```
Web.Config.Debug
Web.Config.Release
```

Comment: thanks, what i did is just created two config file(for MVC 4.0 and 3.0) and one bat file, copyed the corresponding MVC config to default web.config file in Pre build event.